# Is it too much for react native? List Transition with Z dimension

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I wanted to style my application with list transition like on this gif..

[image: --]

I wrote the code on CSS but the thing is I cannot copy that to React Native because it doesn't support "translateZ". So my question is; is it possible to do this on react native? Or is it too much for it?

I also added example code on CSS/HTML.

```css
#viewport {
  background: darkblue;
   position:fixed;
   -webkit-perspective:100px;
   -webkit-perspective-origin:50% 50%;
   border: 2px solid black;
   height: 300px;
   width: 300px;
   left:50%;
   margin-left:-200px;
  }

.div1, .div2, .div3 {
   position:absolute;
   width:80px;
   height:150px;
   left:50%;
   top:50%;
   margin-left:-40px;
   margin-top:-75px;
   background: white;
   border: 1px solid black;
   border-radius: 10px;
}

.div1 {
  transform: translateZ(-20px) translateY(-26px);
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.div2 {
  transform: translateZ(-10px) translateY(-13px);
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.div3 {
  transform: translateZ(0px) translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<div id="viewport">
  <div class="div1">.</div>
  <div class="div2">.</div>
  <div class="div3">.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks sweet btw

Comment: Yeah @Bemmu but it looks like fake animations of hollywood movies for now without coding it. If i find the way to do it, it will be more sweet :)

Comment: It seems like it should be doable. Do you how an example of an existing app that implements this effect?